# Sintaxis de las funciones rename_with y sub - R

Tags: r

Estoy utilizando esta formula que obtuve de uno de estos foros para limpiar los nombres de las columnas de mi data frame( hice un join y me quedaron varias con el `.x` por lo que averiguando logre dar con la siguiente linea de código :

```
rename_with(~ sub("\\.x", "", .), contains(".x"))
```

El problema es que, si bien funciona, no termino de comprender la sintaxis de la misma.

En primer lugar no se que función cumple `~`, sin embargo, entiendo que `"\\.x"` hace referencia a buscar todas aquellas columnas que tengan texto y finalicen en `.x`. Luego, `""` es la cadena de texto por la que se reemplaza(en este caso nada).

Finalmente, no termino de comprender el tercer argumento de la funcion sub(`.`, y lo que seria el segundo argumento de la funcion rename_with( esto es, `contains(".x")`). Intente googlear pero no se me hizo facil. Alguien podria orientarme, ya sea explicandome o diciendome que deberia leer?

Desde ya, gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo entendido que estas sintaxis son para reducir el código,

Si escribimos la misma linea de código, pero con sus respectivos argumentos tendríamos lo siguiente:

```
rename_with(.fn = ~ sub("\\.x", "", .), .cols =  contains(".x"))
```

Donde .fn corresponde a la funcion que queremos aplicarle a cada columna y .cols corresponde a cuales columnas

La funcion rename_with, por defecto viene

```
.cols = everything()
```

Es decir le aplicara la función a todas las columnas

Un ejemplo para tratar de explicarme un poco mejor seria lo siguiente:

```
data_ejemplo = data.frame(
  var1.x = 0,
  var2.y = 0,
  var3.x = 0,
  var4.y = 0
)
```

En cuanto a las sintaxis, entiendo que

```
~ sub("\\.x", "", .) o usar ~ sub("\\.x", "", .x)
```

Hacen referencia a que se esta aplicando una función de "x" a cada columna, ya que otra forma sin usar la cola de chancho y el . seria hacer lo siguiente:

```
data_ejemplo %>%
  rename_with(.fn = function(x){sub("\\.x", "", x)}, .cols =  contains(".x"))
```

Y claramente eso es mucho mas largo

Por otro lado el contains(".x"), aplica la funcion solo a las columnas que contengan en alguna parte de su nombre ".x", si dejaramos vacio el parametro .cols, llegariamos al mismo resultado, ya que solo estamos reduciendo las columnas a aplicar la funcion

Finalmente el sub, entre los 3 parámetros principales, que son

```
sub(pattern = "\\.x", replacement =  "", x = .)
```

El pattern, hace referencia a lo que contenga la cadena no necesariamente en lo que finaliza, en este caso las puntuaciones o caracteres especiales se les antepone un \\
para identificarlas

El replacement, es por lo que deseas reemplazar esa coincidencia y finalmente el x = .
hace referencia a la variable a la cual quieres hacer dichos reemplazos, en este caso como explicamos, a cada columna que contiene un .x

Comment: Muchas gracias! Muy buena y completa la respuesta. Mi duda estaba en que entendia que x= . del tercer argumento de la funcion sub, ya indica las columnas que contienen .x( por lo que estuve leyendo, el"." es una especie de regular expression) y el "contains(".x") me parecia redundante.